# AI reasoning system

Tags: artificial-intelligence, reasoning, reasoner

I'm wondering if there is any system/infrastructure able to do some human reasoning process, for example:

`Context: A is a pen
Question: is A vertical or horizontal
Reasoning process:
1. horizontal is anything parallel to the ground
2. A is parallel to the ground
3. A is horizontal`

The ultimate goal of this reasoning system would be that it's able to generate facts with some pre-defined rules.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there anything you want me to clarify in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with ontologies. You can use [Protege](https://protege.stanford.edu/) which is a free ontology editor equipped with reasoners to infer implicit knowledge. Specifying an ontology as follows will achieve the desired result:

```
ObjectProperty: hasOrientation
    Domain: Object
    Range: Orientation

ObjectProperty: isParallel
    Domain: Object
    Range: Surface

Class: Object

Class: Orientation
    EquivalentTo: {Horizontal , Vertical}

Class: Pen
    SubClassOf: Object

Class: Surface
    EquivalentTo: {Ground , Rock , Wall}

Individual: Ground
    Types: Surface

Individual: Horizontal
    Types: Orientation    
    DifferentFrom: Vertical

Individual: Rock
    Types: Surface

Individual: Vertical
    Types: Orientation
    DifferentFrom: Horizontal

Individual: Wall
    Types: Surface

Individual: myPen
    Types: Pen
    Facts:  isParallel  Ground

Rule: 
    Pen(?aPen), isParallel(?aPen, Ground) -> hasOrientation(?aPen, Horizontal)
    Pen(?aPen), isParallel(?aPen, Wall) -> hasOrientation(?aPen, Vertical)
```

The inference is achieved with `Pen(?aPen), isParallel(?aPen, Ground) -> hasOrientation(?aPen, Horizontal)` which basically states that if `aPen` is a `Pen` and `aPen` is in a `isParallel` relation with `Ground` then `aPen` has a `Horizontal` orientation.

As an aside, you may find [this research](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~torsten/publications/THahmann_COSIT-13.pdf) of interest.